# How to connect Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I recently downloaded Visual Studio Code and I'm trying to figure out how to connect the editor to my Visual Studio Team Services project. Anyone have any success with this?

Comment: VS Code is just a text editor, not a full blown IDE. You cannot open VS projects in it like you do Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you Roman. :-)

Comment: Take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/versioncontrol. There is support for git but if your project already exists in TFVC you will need to use separate command line tools - not so nice.

Comment: uch - Command line tools.. Thanks Alex for you in-site.

Comment: @user167698 you don't need any command line tools. VSTS already supports Git. You can use VS Code and VSTS without problems

Comment: NB: VSTS supports both GIT and TFVC.  For GIT, just use the build in functionality "Clone Git Repository" to set up a new connection to that VSTS repo.  However; when prompted for credentials don't use your VSTS credentials, but use the description & password of a Personal Access Token created for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Download the "[Visual Studio Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)" extension from the marketplace, it allows you to connect to Team Services, monitor your builds and manage your pull requests and work items for your Git repositories.

After you've installed the extension, open either the root folder or a sub-folder of the **cloned Git repository**. Once a Team Services or Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 (or later) repository is detected by the extension, you will need to provide your credentials (if credentials weren't already found). If you are required to provide your credentials, there will be an indicator in the status bar whose message will indicate that you need to login in.

Comment: And it now supports TFS 2015 Update 2 and TFS 2017.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex S. Mentions, Visual Studio Code can already integrate with TFS and Visual Studio Team Services when you're using a Git Repository for source control.

TFVC support is not included, but there is a [nice wrapper around the command line tools available as a plugin](https://github.com/ivangabriele/vscode-tfs). You still need to have either Team Explorer 2013 or Team Explorer 2015 installed on your system, so this doesn't work on Linux or Mac, unfortunately. (Though it could possibly use the Cross Platform Command line Tools for TFS I suppose, pull request anyone?).

Comment: TFVC isn't needed as VSTS supports Git.

Comment: The OP didn't mention TFVC. VSTS is not just the version control component. In fact, Git is probably the most popular version control for non-corporate repositories

Comment: I agree, which is why I mention that the integration already works for git repositories and VSTeam

Comment: Hi can I clarify that we don't need any extension to VSC in order to connect to VS Team Services -> Project -> GIT repo. Also I am still unsure as to the exact command to connect the remote repo in VS Team services.  So much easier in VS2015 - tho I prefer VSC.