# Can not connect to tfvc with visual studio code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc

First of all, I am very new in the programming. I learnt a lot (thanks to my teacher :D) and now I and my 2 friends has a common project. We thought that we could build a webpages with .ASP, jQuery, C#, sql. I am the front-end guy therefore I use Visual Studio Code. We have a common vsts. I downloaded the latest version of visual studio code and the latest version of team services extension, red a lot of documentation that explains how I need to do this. I got this error message: 
(team) No Team Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.

Please someone explain me how can I connect. I would appreciate it, if you make a short and fast tutorial video. I can do almost everything from documentations or tutorials, but now, I really don't know where I am.

Thanks your help in advance! <3

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645416/how-to-connect-visual-studio-code-to-visual-studio-team-services

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know that whoes library/repositroy shoud it be:
After you've installed the extension, open either the "root folder" or a "sub-folder" of the cloned Git repository.

Comment: @vaciechan Are you using Git, or are you using TFVC? They are different things.

Comment: I want to use tfvc. Sorry, but I really don't know, what I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should use the official **[Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)** which released by Microsoft.

It supports both **TFVC** and **GIT** version control type.

> **Clone your Git repository**
>
> With Git, the extension uses the remote origin of your repository to
>   determine how to connect to Team Services (or your Team Foundation
>   Server), in most cases you will need to have a Git repository already
>   cloned locally. If you intend on cloning an existing repository, do so
>   before proceeding. If you do not have a Git repository cloned locally
>   but already have a Team Services account (or a Team Foundation Server
>   instance), you may create a local repository (via `git init`) and once
>   you set the "origin" remote for that local repository, the extension
>   will detect the change to the remote and attempt to contact the Team
>   Services account (or Team Foundation Server).
>
> **Create your TFVC workspace**
>
> With TFVC, the extension uses information about the current workspace
>   to determine how to connect to Team Services (or your Team Foundation
>   Server). Workspaces can be created using the Visual Studio IDE,
>   Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ).
>
> *Note: At this time, you will need to have a local TFVC workspace already available on your local machine. More information about the
>   difference between the two types (and how to determine which one
>   you're using) can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-and-server-workspace-how-can-i-tell-which-one-im-working-with).*

You could also take a look at below videos to help get you started using the extension quickly:

- [Set up the Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6gGfj8WOgg&feature=youtu.be) - *If
  you haven't used the extension before, this video will show you how
  to set it up, create a personal access token and get up and running.*
- [Walkthrough of the Team Services extension for Visual Studio
  Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk6LrzQX4P8&feature=youtu.be) - *This is a walkthrough of most of the features of the Team
  Services extension.*
- [TFVC Source Code Control for Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be) - *This video shows
  you how to set up the TFVC support on Windows and demonstrates much
  of the functionality available for Team Foundation Version Control.*

Above is for windows machine, if you are working on Mac, please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006473/5391065).

Comment: So I need to map&get the project with visual studio 2017 then open visual studio code, and after open the maped folder?

Comment: @vaciechan No,  In order to provide TFVC support in Visual Studio Code, the extension relies on the use of a **TF command line client**. Therefore, you will need to have one already installed and configured. TFVC support will not work without an available command line client. You could use tf.exe command to do the map&get operation.